# How to avoid leaking memory when deallocating libjudy Judy Hash Set (JudyHS) data structures using the JSHFA() macro?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I want to use libjudy to build some data structures to store information keyed on fixed length byte arrays, which means that I need to use the JudyHS structures.  Based on my understanding of the code and the documentation, a key will only be able to access an element consisting of a single machine word, which would be fine since I want to save a pointer to a struct allocated on the heap; however, there is a problem in that there appears to be no way to iterate over the previously stored elements, and the macro used to deallocate the structure (JHSFA), calls free() on the memory used to store the word of data, but provides no mechanism to allow the calling code to deallocate memory that the word points to.  I verified that JHSFA doesn't deallocate user supplied memory using valgrind and the following example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <judy.h>

int
main(
  const int argc,
  const char *argv[]
)
{
  Pvoid_t table = (PWord_t)NULL;
  const size_t allocSize = sizeof("bar") + 1;
  char *bar = calloc(1, allocSize);
  strncpy(bar, "bar", allocSize);
  uint64_t key = UINT32_MAX + 1;
  PWord_t entry;
  JHSI(entry, table, &key, sizeof(key));
  *entry = (Word_t)bar;
  entry = NULL;
  JHSG(entry, table, &key, sizeof(key));
  if (!strncmp(bar, (const char *)(*entry), allocSize)) {
    printf("match\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("no match\n");
  }
  Word_t result;
  JHSFA(result, table);
}
```

Given that this is the case, can some other libjudy user out there point me to a way to avoid a memory leak if this data structure is the only place where I store the data?

Answer (score 0):

JudyHS can't be iterated over. Therefor the typical solution of looping over the entries and freeing the values isn't directly possible. Your options are:

1) Use JudySL and restrict your keys to not having a NULL byte in them. If you need NULL bytes, then you might also consider converting the keys to an escaped format (i.e. one where the NULL byte is a multi-byte escape sequence.)

2) Combine the JudyHS with another ADT that you can iterate over. This ranges in complexity depending on your use case. If you add and remove things from the JudyHS, then its doubtful this can be done in a way that is more efficient than 1). If you only add entires, then a simple linked list, array of pointers, or JudyL will work.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but leaves the question of how to loop over the values in a JudyHS.  There appears to be no macro or function in the library that implements this common case, and I was unable to find any example code.  I read the body of JudyHSFreeArray() in JudyHS.c, but found it quite difficult to decipher to the point where I was comfortable doing a copy/paste job that would be expected to have a high probability of functioning correctly.  I would love to see any further information that you could provide for this.

Comment: I've added some pseudo code for you. That project I reference makes extensive use of libJudy and I hope is a good reference for how to use it.

Comment: I just realized that your question is specifically how to do this with JudyHS and not JudySL. You right, this isn't possible with the api provided fro JudyHS because its not possible iterate over a JudyHS.

In order to do what you want you'll have to put the keys into something you can iterate over. I ran into the same trouble with JudyHS and decided it was easier to use JudySLs instead.

Comment: From the mailing list, with the same question/problem:
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27030794

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the mailing list discussion; I'm stuck with C and not C++, but I may be able to make use of some of the work there.